# Matching capture group multiple times within parent match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Let's say I have a string like this:

> hello blah(1) ndnddnnn div1 - this ;sdhfdkl;a div2 - should i<;oisdjn
>   div3 - be div4 - captured  ois;s;urbb !blah aksdhflakjsfadlfjkbafa;km
>   blah(2) ndnddnnn div35 - also ;sdhfdkl;a div24 - these i<;oisdjn div0 -
>   need div94 - capture  ois;s;urbb !blah world

I'm trying to pull out specific information in between `blah` and `!blah`. This is an example of the information I want:

- 1

  - 1, this
  - 2, should
  - 3, be
  - 4, captured
- 2

  - 35, also
  - 24, these
  - 0, need
  - 94, capture

This is the regex I'm trying to use:

`/blah\((\d)\)(([\s\S]*?div([\d]) - (\w+) )+)[\s\S]*?(?!\!blah)/g`

This is my understanding of the regex string I've defined:

- `blah\((\d)\)`: capture the number within the parens
- `([\s\S]*?div([\d]) - (\w+) )`: some random text preceding the "div", then capture the digit after the div and the word after the `-`. This statement is wrapped in a capture group that I want to match once or more. regex101 told me that I need to wrap this in another capturing group to get all instances. My text within the `blah` and `!blah` is essentially a the divX - YYYYY format preceded by some random text.
- `[\s\S]*?(?!\!blah)`: end with some random text and the look behind match the `!blah`.

[Here is it in action](https://regex101.com/r/xhmmV0/3/)

For some reason, I'm not getting the matches I want, as you can see in the link above. What am I doing wrong? Are some of the assumptions I made above incorrect? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample? I used [`regexObj.exec(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for this situation.

### Sample script :

```js
var str = "hello blah(1) ndnddnnn div1 - this ;sdhfdkl;a div2 - should i<;oisdjn div3 - be div4 - captured ois;s;urbb !blah aksdhflakjsfadlfjkbafa;km blah(2) ndnddnnn div35 - also ;sdhfdkl;a div24 - these i<;oisdjn div0 - need div94 - capture ois;s;urbb !blah world";
var re  = /\((\d)\)|div(\d.?)\s-\s(\w.*?)\s/g;
var ar = [];
while ((res=re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (res[1]) {
    var temp = res[1];
  } else {
    ar.push([temp, res[2], res[3]]);
  }
};
console.log(ar);
```

### Result :

```
[
    ["1", "1", "this"],
    ["1", "2", "should"],
    ["1", "3", "be"],
    ["1", "4", "captured"],
    ["2", "35", "also"],
    ["2", "24", "these"],
    ["2", "0", "need"],
    ["2", "94", "capture"]
]
```

- `\((\d)\)` is used for retrieving the numbers enclosed by `(` and `)`.
- `div(\d.?)\s-\s(\w.*?)\s` is used for retrieving "1" and "this" from `div#1 - this`.

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/uc0or8of/3/)

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dqN9u0/1)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This essentially does what I want, but I was wondering if there was any way to associate the `blah(#)` with the divs that it contains. For example, if the # was a category number, is there any way to associate the first 4 div's with that #? Or should I just regex the larger `blah` -> `!blah` text and then regex each "chunk" within it with a loop?

Comment: @mithunm93 Thank you for your reply. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. The retrieved data was imported to an array. ``#`` of ``blah(#)`` is used at 1st index of the array. You can use the data from the array. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I was trying to figure out if there was any way to do that without using the loop, but this is actually pretty clean. Thanks!

Comment: @mithunm93 Welcome. Thank you, too.